# Association Rule mining using R

Tags: r, data-mining

I am trying to find association rules for a file that contains cosmetic product names as columns and each transaction in a row contains either 0 or 1 for that particular product in a column. There are 15 columns in the dataset. I tried reading the data into data.frame and ran apriori algorithm in arules library. However the rules output included a combination of columns that had zeros in it. For example see below

```
inspect(rules.sorted[1:20])
   lhs                    rhs             support confidence     lift
1  {Brushes=1}         => {Nail.Polish=1}   0.149  1.0000000 3.571429
2  {Brushes=1,                                                       
    Lipstick=0}        => {Nail.Polish=1}   0.100  1.0000000 3.571429
3  {Bag=0,                                                           
    Brushes=1}         => {Nail.Polish=1}   0.129  1.0000000 3.571429
4  {Brushes=1,                                                       
    Eyebrow.Pencils=0} => {Nail.Polish=1}   0.138  1.0000000 3.571429
```

if you look at above output all 4 rules are same but for some reason algorithm is picking combination of other products whose value is '0'. How do I avoid that?

Comment: have you tried replacing 0 with NA?

Comment: I am confused. If we replace 0 with NA then we might lose the meaning of data. 0 means there was no sale for that item. Am I missing something here?